# Collapse editor resource panel in Google scripts editor

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

Is it possible to remove or collapse the editor resource panel in Google Script Editor?
I often use a split screen to display the code and watch the results simultaneously, but there is limited real estate when working on a laptop, and I don't need that panel to be there all the time.
I've been super pleased with this new editor, and truthfully, this is the only thing that irks me about it.
If it can't be done, then I'll give it up and accept my fate.
Much appreciated!

[image: Split screen with 2 tabs and the amount of space used by the resource panel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to hide the Google Apps Script editor "resources panel" but you could hide it by using the web-browser developer tools or a web browser extension like Grease Monkey to run a user-script.

One way without using browser extensions, is by adding  `display:none` to the styles attribute of the electement "resources panel" element. The effect of this will temporary, you will have to apply it again if you refresh the editor and the next time that you opened.

At this time this element has the following CSS selector: `#yDmH0d > c-wiz:nth-child(13) > div > div.Hu42fb > div.OX2gTc.DqVtX.dLSs8b.p7Awzb.fb0g6 > div.Kp2okb.SQyOec` but this might change at any time without notice, so the best might be to learn about how to find the element.

1. Right click over the Files label, then select Inspect
2. Move the mouse pointer over the elements until you find the one that corresponds to the "resource panel"

[image]

3. In this case the element include a style attribute, you only have to add `display: none;`.

Resources

- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/

Comment: I'm not the OP but thanks for this - works great.  BTW: three months later the Div ID is still "Kp2okb SQyOec".